# Why does my service get instantiated multiple times?

Tags: android

IIUC, there should only be one instance of a given Android service, it is a singleton.

However, my service gets instantiated multiple times, although I
do nothing for it.

When the service crashes (for example when I uninstall the app through adb), it
gets scheduled for restart ("Scheduling restart of crashed service.. "). I
understand this is an effect of the service being sticky.

After that, when my app starts, it calls startService() and bindService(), and
the service gets appropriately started and bound. But the service is then
reinstantiated and onCreate() is called repeatedly, as many times it was
scheduled for restart.

Each instance then wait for clients to bind and register, but onBind() is only
called in the "main" service instance. The additional instances wait a bit for
client to bind, and since that doesn't happen, they call stopSelf().

But stopSelf() has absolutely no effect in these "dead" instances, onDestroy()
is never called.

The "main" service instance does work as expected, and when it decides to call
stopSelf(), onDestroy() is indeed called.

Worse, all these dead instances accumulate, they never gets destroyed.
Therefore, their only possible end is a crash (which happen every time I
launch/install through adb), and thus scheduled restart.

So that in the end I get many of these dead instances, which are restarted
progressively once by minute approximately.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: Show us a screenshot of your 'accumlated' dead instances

Comment: The code is complex, extracting a snippet is not easy. I would need to write a small test. About a screenshot, at the moment that's not possible, because this issue is long gone now. I changed something in the past, but I can't remember what exactly and the issue is simply gone. I have it all on SVN so I should be able to reproduce the problem, but time is lacking at the moment. I'll see what I can do about it.

Comment: +1 I have also seen this problem and haven't yet found a solution. I see it happen when the application gets updated. I have a remote service in a separate process. When the installer kills the process hosting the service, Android schedules it for restart. If the user starts the App before then, it looks like Android (wrongly) starts **another instance** of the service in the same process. Very messy and hard to reproduce. Your question is 2 years old, have you found a solution?

Comment: Just for the record, I have had this issue in a Production application as well. The application runs its service in a separate process to the UI. I never call `bindService` anywhere, only `startService`. Haven't found a solution or a way to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

I got similar behavior if I use eclipse to restart an app with a remote service. According to logcat, system consider the killed service had a crash and tried to restart the service. At the same time, the service has been restarted with the restarted app. For some unknown reason, Android system does not realize there is already a running service, and tries to start a new one.

It happens several times on Optimus one, Galaxy tab, and EVO 3D. It is fine with Nexus one.

Comment: What you're saying is pretty much what happened to me. I do have a service running in a separate process. Except that this problem is gone now. It doesn't occur any more. I don't know what I changed exactly, it's been a while, but it just doesn't happen anymore, even if I use eclipse as you say.

Comment: This problem happens on and off for me. I am still digging the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because I haven't seen your code, this is just a guess: Maybe you have a memory leak that prevents the service from destroying properly. That's the only reason I could think of to get multiple instances of service. For example, if you service is holding on to some object that also have a reference to your service. It happens a lot with inner classes.

Check out this video from Google I/O to see if this problem applies to your services and how to find it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&feature=player_embedded

Comment: It might well be something like this.. But as I said in other comments, I can't reproduce the problem easily anymore, it's solved. But it maybe was a memory leak, not sure.

Comment: This can't be right. Even if you have a memory leak that prevents your service instance reclaimed by the garbage collector, Android should still call `onDestroy()` on it and it should be "gone" as far as Android is concerned, even if it is still around in the memory of the VM.

Comment: The video's an hour long. Do you know which part of the video relates most to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you use the section to be excecuted in `onstart()` . if ur starting the service by `onclick` button or like clicking on icon multiple time means ,what it will do is if service is already running means ,it will go to onstart(),so the method is excecuting again and again its not that service is starting multiple times .... ur method is running for multiple time ,This i told accornding to my guess may be exact code will be Explaind properlly

Comment: OP states that **`onCreate()` is called repeatedly** and he has multiple instances of the service (multiple objects). Your answer doesn't address the problem that is posed by OP.

Comment: Unless service is destroyed. oncreate will not called repeatedly,it will go to on start only,may be in his case service is destroyed so that multiple time oncreate() is getting called......

Comment: No, actually. As I said in one of my comments, there is an Android bug  that causes multiple instances of the `Service` object to be created. That means `onCreate()` is called on a second instance of the `Service` even though there is already an existing instance that has **not been destroyed**. It doesn't happen normally, but there are cases (for example: when the app is being updated), where this does actually happen. Believe it or not.

Comment: David Wasser- Thanks ,In my case it never happened okay give me some case i will try and let u know....

Comment: This is happening with me, Multiple times onCreate method getting called of Service

Answer (score -1):

if your app exit on crash or kill the process it belongs to like System.exit(), it will start after your app exit or start if your service is running in the same process with Application.
Because you kill the process, and Android detect your service should not stop, so Android restart it for you after your app exit. And why service start again after app restart, I think it is Android's bug, it reallocate a new process to your app instead of using the process allocate to your service.

So, how to solve this problem?
just set the attribute android:process=":background"(whatever you want here, starts with :) to your service node in AndroidManifest.xml. hope it helps you.

Comment: I have this problem in an app that already has the service in a background process, so I don't think that's a complete solution. Also, moving a service to a separate process could involve a lot of work due to concurrency issues, so I think that should be approached with caution.